# Discord.js if the client hasn't the permission, he return a message.send

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I got the error: `TypeError: client.user.hasPermission is not a function`

I've tried similar thing to do (searching, adding diffrent things). but i can't figure/find it out.

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

```js
 if(!client.user.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send(embed2)
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send(embed)
    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Voeg een cijfer tussen de 1 en de 100 toe.")
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]).then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`Ik heb voor jou ${args[0]} berichten verwijderd.`).then(message => {message.delete(5000)})
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.

```js
if(!message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {  return message.channel.send(embed2) }
```

Thanks for helping everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when dealing with any API it's important to use the API documentation for the software at hand. If the API documentation is poor, I would generally recommend selecting a different piece of software. Nobody's got time to try and guess their way through terribly documented APIs and the results are rarely stable.

In the case of Discord.js, it seems reasonably decent in conjunction with the guides. I've never used it before, so given that your code is telling you that "client.user.hasPermission" is not a function, I checked the docs on Client.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

This says that property `user` is of type `ClientUser`.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser

This class clearly has no `hasPermission` method available. I then did a Google search for `discord.js check user permission`. The first hit is a guid for permissions in Discord.js:

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html

This tells us that permissions are based around guilds and guild members. There *is* a `hasPermission` method, but that's on class `GuildMember`, *not* on class `ClientUser`.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in the bigger picture of your software - it is often helpful on StackOverflow if you always provide a brief overview of your wider problem or task at hand, not just the tightly focused specific problem you have. As it stands, all I can tell you is that the error you got was predictable and correct; you're calling a method that doesn't exist on that class; that permissions appear to be part of the guild system; and that therefore, you need to change your code to understand guilds and guild members if the things you are doing are based around permissions checks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch a guild user (using the client id) then see if user.hasPermission

```js
let clientUser = guild.members.fetch(client.id); 
// if that doesn't work, append .cache after .members and before .fetch
// ie: guild.members.cache.fetch(client.id);

if(!clientUser.hasPermission("permission to test") { }
```